# Wireless N in Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A (Intel Ultimate-N 6300)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel, centrino

after install a fresh Ubuntu LTS 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) in my Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A the wireless network become super unstable.

After boot I can only connect for a few seconds and traffic stops to flow but the wireless stays connected.

I believe my driver is Intel Ultimate-N 6300, and my router is Thomson TG784n.

Comment: Is traffic absolutely stopped or is it just repeatedly interrupted or very slow?

Comment: absolutely stopped (in and out), I checked in System Monitor -> Resources -> Network History

Comment: OK, then it seems to be an different issue compared to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/836250) which has to do with wireless-n networks and the hardware crypto implementation. Maybe you can try playing around with the module parameters for iwlwifi anyway...

Comment: when i run this "sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" it seams to become more stable